# Cohomology with coefficient $\mathbb{Q}(n)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

What is the definition of 
$$\mathrm{H}^i(X,\mathbb{Q}(n))$$
for a variety $X$? and What is its relation with $\mathrm{Ext}^*(\mathbb{Q}(0),\mathbb{Q}(n))$?

Another question: Is this a notion which is defined for certain cohomology theories or has a motion version?

A good reference is also very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If it were $\mathbf Q_l(n)$ I would think it a "Tate twist". Here I don't know :(. Anyway, presumably you've seen this somewhere so it probably wouldn't hurt to say where that is.

Comment: @Hoot Yes, it's the Tate twist but it also exists in the category of Hodge structures over Q and is denoted by Q(n). And also in every cohomology theory over Q. This notion appears in a vast literature about motives and I ask here a readable reference.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point, at least for the motivic part of your question, might be M. Hanamura's paper "Theory of mixed motives" which is freely available online. The motivic cohomology group $H^{i}_{\mathcal{M}}(X,\mathbb{Q}(n))$ is defined in the first few pages.